# speeding up a loop with loop-carried values in R

Tags: r, performance, rcpp

I'm trying to speed up code that takes time series data and limits it to a maximum value and then stretches it forward until sum of original data and the "stretched" data are the same.

I have a more complicated version of this that is taking 6 hours to run on 100k rows. I don't think this is vectorizable because it uses values calculated on prior rows - is that correct?

```
x <- c(0,2101,3389,3200,1640,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=rep(0,length(x)))
remainder <- 0
upperlimit <- 2000
for(i in 1:length(dat$x)){
  if(dat$x[i] >= upperlimit){
    dat$y[i]  <- upperlimit
  } else {
    dat$y[i] <- min(remainder,upperlimit)
  }
  remainder  <-  remainder + dat$x[i] - dat$y[i]
}
dat
```

I understand you can use `ifelse` but I don't think `cumsum` can be used to carry forward the remainder - `apply` doesn't help either as far as I know. Do I need to resort to `Rcpp`? Thank you greatly.

Comment: `upperlimit` never changes, so you should get a big performance boost if you calculate `dat$x >= upperlimit` first.

Comment: General advice: data.frame subsettting is slow. Work with vectors in your loop and combine the results into a data.frame in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and implemented this in `Rcpp` and made some adjustments to the `R` function:

```
require(Rcpp);require(microbenchmark);require(ggplot2);

limitstretchR <- function(upperlimit,original) {
  remainder  <- 0
  out <- vector(length=length(original))
  for(i in 1:length(original)){
    if(original[i] >= upperlimit){
      out[i]  <- upperlimit
    } else {
      out[i] <- min(remainder,upperlimit)
    }
    remainder  <-  remainder + original[i] - out[i]
  }
  out
}
```

The `Rcpp` function:

```
cppFunction('
  NumericVector limitstretchC(double upperlimit, NumericVector original) {
    int n = original.size();
    double remainder = 0.0;
    NumericVector out(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (original[i] >= upperlimit) {
          out[i] = upperlimit;
        } else {
          out[i] = std::min<double>(remainder,upperlimit);
        }
      remainder = remainder + original[i] - out[i];
    }
    return out;
  }
')
```

Testing them:

```
x <- c(0,2101,3389,3200,1640,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
original <- rep(x,20000)
upperlimit <- 2000
system.time(limitstretchR(upperlimit,original))
system.time(limitstretchC(upperlimit,original))
```

That yielded 80.655 and 0.001 seconds respectively. Native `R` is quite bad for this. However, I ran a `microbenchmark` (using a smaller vector) and got some confusing results.

```
res <- microbenchmark(list=
    list(limitstretchR=limitstretchR(upperlimit,rep(x,10000)),
    limitstretchC=limitstretchC(upperlimit,rep(x,10000))),
        times=110,
        control=list(order="random",warmup=10))
print(qplot(y=time, data=res, colour=expr) + scale_y_log10())
boxplot(res)
print(res)
```

If you were to run that you would see nearly identical results for both functions. This is my first time using `microbenchmark`, any tips?

Comment: For those following along, the original version using a `data.frame` finally finished. It took 1317.996 seconds.